# Get next sequence from table in insert statement to another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sequence

I have 3 tables

- `Table_A` has a bunch of rows
- `Table_B` where rows are going to be inserted with data from `Table_A`
- `Table_C` holds a number (integer) called `code_number`

I have a stored procedure (`sp_getNextCode`) that selects the current `code_number` from `Table_C`, creates and returns a `varchar` code string with this number (like `yyyyMMdd + cast(code_number as varchar)` or something) and updates the `Table_C` `code_number` with the next value (`code_number+1`)

So far so good.

Now I want to insert a number of rows from `Table_A` to `Table_B` WITHOUT THE USE OF CURSOR
using a

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B 
    SELECT .... FROM TABLE_A
```

Again so far so good

The problem is that one of the values in the above insert statement has to be the output of the stored procedure `sp_getNextCode`.

- I cannot use the stored procedure in the statement
- I cannot create a function with the same code as `sp_getNextCode` as the functions cannot    have `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`

I don't have the option of SQL Server 2012 (which has a sequence) only SQL Server 2008

Is there any way to achieve this or the only way is with cursors (I REALLY want to avoid the cursor cause im talking about thousands of rows that need to be inserted and it takes too long )

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures, since that prefix has been reserved by Microsoft for its own use. Try to avoid it whenever you can

Comment: thanks marc_s i know about that i just named it like that for the sake of the example :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is a way: Create a stored procedure to read from table_A, inserts ino table_b and updates table_C:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @last_value=last_vale FROM  Table_C;

SELECT @records_to_insert = COUNT(*) 
FROM Table_A
WHERE <Conditions>

INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT <Fields>,...., @last_value + ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(ORDER BY <some ordering criteria>)
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE <Conditions>

UPATE Table_C
SET last_value = @last_value + @records_to_insert +1

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I am ommiting some details as the transformation of the numbers to the formatted code, exception handling and rollback, but I hope you can get the idea.

The trick is to use the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY...) function to obtain a unique number for each row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Ok it wasnt 100% what i needed but it helped me solve the problem i had . i only needed to make a function that gets @last_value and ROW_NUMBER() and returns a new varchar()